# With clause for multiple output cursor

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure which consists of four output cursors.

All four cursors need the same filter condition using where. Something like this:

```
WHERE NOT u.userid IN (SELECT DISTINCT emailid 
                       FROM quote q 
                       WHERE TRUNC(q.dateofenquiry) >= TRUNC(sysdate - 30))
```

Is there any way to not repeat same code for multiple times in same stored procedure for multiple output cursors?

Keep coding.....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't need cursors at all, but that is a different issue.

I would also recommend that you use `NOT EXISTS`, structuring the condition as:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM quote q
                  WHERE q.emailid = u.userid AND
                        TRUNC(q.dateofenquiry) >= TRUNC(sysdate - 30)
                 )
```

Then, you want an index on `quote(emailid, trunc(dateofenquiry))` -- assuming your database has function based indexes.  This will optimize performance.

If you want to "simplify" the code, you could create a temporary table:

```
create table temp_quote as
    select distinct emailid
    from quote q
    where TRUNC(q.dateofenquiry) >= TRUNC(sysdate - 30);
```

And define an index on the table:

```
create index idx_quote_emailid on temp_quote(emailid);
```

And access it the same way:

```
where not exists (select 1 from quote_temp q where q.emailid = u.userid)
```